# How to make a readonly text field writable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enable the text field (its id is `name_text_field`) when clicking the button (its id is `name_button`). But my code is not working.

Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<input type="text" id="name_text_field" readonly="readonly" value="name">
<button id="name_button" onclick="enableTxt()" style="color: #009dcd; color: #009dcd; border: none; background-color: #ffffff;">name</button>
```

Here is my **JavaScript** code:

```
function enableTxt() {
  document.getElementById("name_text_field").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by enable, you want to make it writable?

Comment: Are you changing the readOnly property or the disabled property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to make it writable.

Because you are setting the `readOnly` property you should change `readOnly` property to `false`.

```
function enableTxt() {
  document.getElementById("name_text_field").readOnly = false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fL0yajuv/)

Or you can make it `disabled` in HTML, then your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` and `readonly` are two completely different things.

If you want your element to start disabled, use

```
<input type="text" id="name_text_field" value="name" disabled>
```

Demo:

```js
function enableTxt() {
  document.getElementById("name_text_field").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name_text_field" value="name" disabled>
<button id="name_button" onclick="enableTxt()" style="color: #009dcd; color: #009dcd; border: none; background-color: #ffffff;">name</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function enableTxt() {
  document.getElementById('name_text_field').readOnly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You were attempting to change `disabled` when you really should have been changing `readonly`. You could also just use disabled and leave readonly out all together.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name_text_field" disabled="true" value="name">
<button id="name_button" onclick="enableTxt()" style="color: #009dcd; color: #009dcd; border: none; background-color: #ffffff;">name</button>
```

JS:

```
function enableTxt() {
  document.getElementById("name_text_field").disabled = false;
}
```

Hope that helps & here is a [demo for proof!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogZYZK)